# How to remove DateTime substring from string

Tags: c#, string, datetime, string-formatting

I have a bunch of strings, some of which have one of the following formats:

```
"TestA (3/12/10)"
"TestB (10/12/10)"
```

The `DateTime` portion of the strings will always be in `mm/dd/yy` format.

What I want to do is remove the whole DateTime part including the parenthesis. If it was always the same length I would just get the index of `/` and subtract that by the number of characters up to and including the `(`. But since the `mm` portion of the string could be one or two characters, I can't do that.

So is there a way to do a `.Contains` or something to see if the string contains the specified `DateTime` format?

Comment: FYI: When you say `mm`, it generally means zero-padded. If it's not zero-padded, it's usually just referred to as `m` (or often `M`, since `m` can be confused with "minutes", depending on your language).

Comment: What are the format constraints on the rest of the string?  Will it ever have a space otherwise (i.e. could you search for the first space and just truncate there?)  What about parentheses?

Comment: This would be a good candidate for RegEx with a capture.  Another alternative, if there's only one ( and ) in each string, is to use `LastIndexOf` for the closing ).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a Regular Expression to strip out the possible date portions if you can be sure they would consistently be in a certain format using the [`Regex.Replace()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) method :

```
var updatedDate = Regex.Replace(yourDate,@"\(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\)","");
```

You can [see a working example of it here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7teQP7), which yields the following output :

```
TestA (3/12/10)  > TestA
TestB (10/12/10) > TestB
TestD (4/5/15)   > TestC
TestD (4/6/15)   > TestD
```

Comment: Everyone's answer worked, just marking this one right because of the working example posted.

Answer (score 2):

You could always use a regular expression to replace the strings

Here is an example

```
var regEx = new Regex(@"\(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\)");
var text = regEx.Replace("TestA (3/12/10)", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a RegEx for this. I recommend:

```
\(\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\)
```

See [RegExr](http://regexr.com/3d5ng) for it working.

Answer (score 1):

Regex could be used for this, something such as:

```
string replace = "TestA (3/12/10) as well as TestB (10/12/10)";
string replaced = Regex.Replace(replace, "\\(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+\\)", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding this correctly you want to just acquire the test name of each string. Copy this code to a button click event.

```
string Old_Date = "Test SomeName(3/12/10)";
string No_Date = "";
int Date_Pos = 0;
Date_Pos = Old_Date.IndexOf("(");
No_Date = Old_Date.Remove(Date_Pos).Trim();
MessageBox.Show(No_Date, "Your Updated String", MessageBoxButton.OK);
```

To sum it up in one line of code

```
No_Date = Old_Date.Remove(Old_Date.IndexOf("(")).Trim();
```